# Permission denied when trying to execute python process from DotNet Core MVC project

Tags: python, c#, permissions, permission-denied

I've created a DotNet Core Razor MVC project and in there, I have created a directory called `python`. Within that python directory, I have created a python script called `myscript.py`.

Following the [real-time chat example for SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc), I have added a function to my `ChatHub` which is supposed to execute `myscript.py`:

```
private string ProcessMessage(string message)
{
    ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
    start.FileName = "/Users/SomeUser/Documents/Code/VisualStudio/MyProject/MyProject/python/myscript.py";
    start.Arguments = message;
    start.UseShellExecute = false;// Do not use OS shell
    start.CreateNoWindow = true; // We don't need new window
    start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;// Any output, generated by application will be redirected back
    start.RedirectStandardError = true; // Any error in standard output will be redirected back (for example exceptions)
    using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
        {
            string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); // Here are the exceptions from our Python script
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); // Here is the result of StdOut(for example: print "test")
            return result;
        }
    }

}
```

Notice I have provided the full path to `start.FileName`. However, when I run this, I get a permission denied error.

I've tried various combinations of that path (e.g. `~/python/myscript.py`)

How can I resolve this? I'm running VS for Mac, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Start Visual Studio as administrator maybe?

Comment: @Berkay Hmm, I'm on a mac - there is no `start as administrator` command and even if there was, that would not guarantee that the code would work in production, no?

Comment: Then try execute chmod 777 to the folder.

Comment: @Berkay I've already allowed `everyone` to read and write that folder, and I have also tried chmod 777, but the issue remains.

Comment: I have the same problem. This used to work until recently on windows. Running visual studio as administrator did not help.